# Using a series to calculate pi in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
pi/2 = 1 + 1/3 + (1*2) / (3*5) + (1*2*3) / (3*5*7) + ...
```

Okay, let's try this again.

I need to write a function that takes the max error as a parameter for the value of pi and returns the calculated value of pi and the number of iterations necessary to get to that point. I can't use a recursive algorithm.

Thus far I have:

```
def piEuler (x):
    count = 0.0
    approx = 0.0
    approx2 = 1.0
    error = math.pi/2 - approx2
    while error > x:
        count = count + 1
        approx3 = approx + approx2
        error = math.pi/2 - approx3
        #print error
        approx = approx + approx2
        approx2 = approx2 * count/(count + 2)
        #print approx2
    final = math.pi - error
    return final, count
```

The issue is that the program is returning a negative value. The error should converge to zero. I need to be able to subtract my error from the accepted value of pi to get an approximate value from the series. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your denominator terms don't look correct. Shouldn't you being calculating the product of `3*5*...*(2*k+1)` for `k=1,2,..,n/2`? Looks like you're doing `3*4*5*...*n`. This would give you a larger number and would explain why the series is summing to a number greater than `pi/2` and therefore making the error term increase in absolute value (but decrease in actual value, i.e. become negative).

Comment: @JoelCornett You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jon-Eric: Good call, posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were incorrectly implementing the algorithm. Rather than doing `pi/2 = 1 + 1/3 + (1*2)/(3*5) + (1*2*3)/(3*5*7) + ...`, it looks like your code is doing `pi/2 = 1 + 1/3 + (1*2)/(3*4) + (1*2*3)/(3*4*5) + ...`.

Since the denominators will end up being smaller, you'll be increasing the sum by a greater amount, resulting no doubt in an overshoot and consequently a negative error.

The problem lies in this line:

```
approx2 = approx2 * count/(count + 2)
```

As you can see, when `count` is even, `count + 2` will be even. An easy fix would be to change this to:

```
approx2 = approx2 * count/(2 * count + 1)
```

Here is a example algorithm that works, but uses the relative error between terms rather than the absolute error (wouldn't want to give everything away ;) ):

```
from __future__ import division

def half_pi(max_err=10**-6, max_iter=10000):
    partial_sum = cur_term = 1
    n = 1
    while abs(t) > max_err and n < max_iter:
        cur_term = cur_term * (n / (2 * n + 1))
        partial_sum += cur_term
        n += 1
    return partial_sum, n
```

Comment: With the change of the defined approx2 and a few minor bugs, this worked perfectly. Negative numbers are never an issue when the series converges to zero. It will only get infinitely closer. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
import math

def piEuler(x):

    halfpi    = math.pi / 2.0
    count     = 0
    approx    = 1.0
    divisor   = 1
    numerator = 1
    while True:
        count     += 1
        numerator *= count
        divisor   *= 2*count + 1
        approx    += float(numerator) / float(divisor)
        error      = halfpi - approx

        if error < x:
            return (math.pi - error), count
```

The basic differences are:

1. By switching the terminating condition of the loop to a test/break, I can remove the manual calculation of the second term of the series
2. Careful use of int and float datatypes (this may have been your problem)
3. Better naming of the variables leads to easier debugging

Answer (score 0):

You should try to rewrite the routine such that the smallest term in the sequence, *approx2* in your code, has to be greater than error.

Also you have 'math.pi' in your last error calculation. Does it have to be math.pi/2 ?

It seems the nature of the error is oscillating also!

Comment: On the contrary, the error would be monotonically decreasing, given that the partial sum is monotonically increasing.