# How do I calculate the value of pi using series in python?

Tags: python, pi

I'm a newbie in programming. Our class is using Python. I'm trying to calculate the value of pi over the range k = [0,5] and output the result indicating the value of k and the result value of pi. The equation we have to use is π=√12+(-3)^k/2k+1. Below is my code. I'm probably doing something wrong, but don't know. Thanks for your help.

```
k = range(0,5)
print("k:", list(k) )
series = [i+i for i in k]
print("series:", series)
sum = sum(series)

pi = math.sqrt(12)
numerator = (-3)pow(k)
denominator = 2(series) + 1
var = numerator/denominator
calculation = value/var
print("calculation")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I've added the python tag.

Comment: http://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-archimedes/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow.

So, there are a few things wrong with your code:

The first thing is that you should have the `import math` statement at the start of your code (unless you just excluded it). This allows you to use `math.sqrt()` and `math.pow()`

The next thing is that for the line that says `numerator = (-3)pow(k)` you should instead write 
`numerator = math.pow(-3, k)`
The first argument in math.pow is the number you're using, and the second is the exponent that is applied to that number.

So your code should then look like this:

```
import math

k = range(0,5)
print("k:", list(k) )
series = [i+i for i in k]
print("series:", series)
sum = sum(series)

pi = math.sqrt(12)
numerator = math.pow(-3,k)
denominator = 2(series) + 1
var = numerator/denominator
calculation = value/var
print("calculation")
```

And even then, we still run into some problems...
You're trying to raise -3 to the k power, but you initialize k as a range, from 0 to 5. You can't do this.

You want to raise -3 to the k power, and k is each number between 0 and 5. So, considering that this looks like a homework question, you'll have to figure out how to use each number in the range, and set it equal to k. Then calculate the value of pi for k = 0, then for k = 1, and on.

You might want to consider using a for loop, or list comprehension if you're not allowed to use loops yet.

***Otherwise***, take a look at this other [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016386/using-a-series-to-calculate-pi-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve the same problem for my Python class, but it's (-3)^-k. I'm wondering if that's a transcription error you made. If so, you may have better results.